# Calculate rolling exponentially weighted correlations using covariance and standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I would like to calculate rolling the pairwise correlation between two columns in dataframe `df` (`df['A']` and `df['B']`) using the following logic:

> A 100-period exponentially weighted covariance divided by the 100-period exponentially weighted standard deviations

[image: Desired Output]

I looked at `pandas.ewmcov`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewmcov.html but it appears to be deprecated.

Comment: can you share the data with us

Comment: I think this is just a simple pearson correlation which pandas applies using ```df.corr```. The  only difference is calculating the ewma which can be done via ```df.ewm```.